# Record average cpu and memory of a single process over time

Tags: ubuntu, memory, cpu, performance, process

I have read a few threads about this but none of them seems to answer my questions.

I have a ubuntu machine and need to record average %cpu and %memory usage of a single process between a start time and an end time. Basically I am running some tools which will stress test the process and I need the averages during that time only.

Top -p  gives only instantaneous values and not the average.